# Rails and RSpec: `rake spec` runs all specs twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec-rails

I set up a new Rails 4 app using RSpec. But when running `rake rspec`, all the examples are run twice:

```
rake spec
[deprecated] I18n.enforce_available_locales will default to true in the future. If you really want to skip validation of your locale you can set I18n.enforce_available_locales = false to avoid this message.
/Users/josh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby -S rspec ./spec/controllers/dashboards_controller_spec.rb ./spec/models/member_spec.rb ./spec/requests/members_spec.rb ./spec/routing/members_routing_spec.rb
[deprecated] I18n.enforce_available_locales will default to true in the future. If you really want to skip validation of your locale you can set I18n.enforce_available_locales = false to avoid this message.
 11/11 |============================================ 100 ============================================>| Time: 00:00:00 

Finished in 0.21233 seconds
11 examples, 0 failures

Randomized with seed 15954

/Users/josh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby -S rspec ./spec/controllers/dashboards_controller_spec.rb ./spec/models/member_spec.rb ./spec/requests/members_spec.rb ./spec/routing/members_routing_spec.rb
[deprecated] I18n.enforce_available_locales will default to true in the future. If you really want to skip validation of your locale you can set I18n.enforce_available_locales = false to avoid this message.
 11/11 |============================================ 100 ============================================>| Time: 00:00:00 

Finished in 0.18831 seconds
11 examples, 0 failures

Randomized with seed 24248
```

I have found some other (old) questions about this, but couldn't find a solution for me. How should I try to debug this? Running `rspec` works like a charm, but I'm eager to find out what's the problem here.

Here's my `spec_helper.rb`:
https://github.com/jmuheim/transition/blob/master/spec/spec_helper.rb

And here's the original Rails project:
https://github.com/jmuheim/transition

**Update**

I found that the `spec` rake task seems to be defined twice (notice the `/` that separates the description of each task):

```
$ rake -T | grep spec
...
rake spec                               # Run all specs in spec directory (excluding plugin specs) / Run RSpec code examples
...
```

One of them is described with `Run all specs in spec directory (excluding plugin specs)`, one with `Run RSpec code examples`.

`Run RSpec code examples` seems to come from [`rspec/core/rake_task.rb`](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/blob/master/lib/rspec/core/rake_task.rb#L72). `Run all specs in spec directory (excluding plugin specs)` seems to come from [`rspec/rails/tasks/rspec.rake`](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/blob/master/lib/rspec/rails/tasks/rspec.rake#L12).

It seems to me that only one of them should exist?!

**Update 2**

It seems to be a problem with `rspec-rails` being in both the `test` and `development` groups. I added an issue about this here: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/904

Comment: post your spec_helper.rb

Comment: Move `gem 'rspec-rails'` from `group :test, :development` to `group :test` in `Gemfile` - solve problem to me

Answer (score 3):

For me this was due to a duplicate entry in my .rspec file. Can't tell if that was the problem here because the .rspec file's in the .gitignore but basically if you do this:

```
-- format progress
-- format documentation
```

In your rspec file you will see the tests output twice.

Answer (score 2):

```
config.around(:each) do |example|
     ......

    DatabaseCleaner.start
    example.run # <================================= remove this
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
.......
  end
```

you need to remove `example.run` call from your spec help. also, setup up your database cleaner `start` & `clean` methods using `config.before(:each)` & `config.after(:each)` hooks

```
config.before(:each) do
  DatabaseCleaner.start
end

config.after(:each) do
  DatabaseCleaner.clean
end
```

so you start `DatabaseCleaner` BEFORE every test & clean AFTER every test

Comment: Sadly this doesn't change anything. And AFAIK the around filter is exactly for something like this.

Comment: PS: I updated my question with a link to the Rails project hosted on GitHub.

Comment: @JoshuaMuheim I am pretty sure you should not run manually examples, around hook is ran automatically before/after examples.

My $0.02: Try join all RSpec.configure call into one

Comment: In fact, something was wrong with the `around` hook, I had some other troubles with it. So I changed it to `before` and an `after` hook, which solved the other troubles, but not the one in this thread. ;-)

Comment: I updated my question though with new insights: it seems that the `spec` task is defined twice!

Answer (score 2):

For me, the issue was a deprecated require as discussed [here](https://github.com/dchelimsky/rspec/issues/68) in the specs I inherited. I just needed to remove the following line from `spec_helper.rb`:

```
require 'rspec/autorun'
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is as easy as it is stupid:

I had another `spec` task declared in my `Rakefile`:

```
# http://blog.revathskumar.com/2011/12/run-rspec-as-rake-task.html
require 'rspec/core/rake_task'
RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new(:spec)
task default: :spec
```

Don't know why I added it there. After removing it, it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue because RSpec has its own rake task running the specs automatically when running the `:default` task, and I have added the following code to my `Rakefile` (found on the Internet):

```
require 'rspec/core/rake_task'
require 'cucumber/rake/task'

RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new
Cucumber::Rake::Task.new

task default: %i[spec cucumber]
```

which is actually re-defining a second time the RSpec (and Cucumber) task. I changed it to the following:

```
task default: %i[spec cucumber]
```

and now it is executed only once.

Here is the complete `Rakefile`:

```
# Add your own tasks in files placed in lib/tasks ending in .rake,
# for example lib/tasks/capistrano.rake, and they will automatically be available to Rake.

require File.expand_path('../config/application', __FILE__)

Rails.application.load_tasks

task default: %i[spec cucumber]
```

FYI: From a Rails 4.2, RSpec 3 and Cucumber 3 app.

Answer (score 0):

### Double test runs on CI

I was getting double `rspec` runs because the Rails `spec` task was clashing with the task defined by `RSpec` - but only on CI. The difference for me was locally I invoke:

```
bundle exec rake
```

Which doesn't have `RAILS_ENV` explicity set. This is fine because the project's `spec_helper.rb` sets `ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'`.

But on CI, the ENV already has `RAILS_ENV=test` set which leads to the Rails `spec` task also being defined, leading to double test runs.

In summary:

```
bundle exec rake                  # => 1 test run
RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rake   # => 2 test runs
```

### The fix

**Clear `task(:spec)` after loading `Rails.application.load_tasks`** (if you want to define the `:spec` task yourself).

```
diff --git a/Rakefile b/Rakefile
index 0f4fb7e0..94f7236a 100644
--- a/Rakefile
+++ b/Rakefile
@@ -6,14 +6,16 @@ require File.expand_path('../config/application', __FILE__)

 Rails.application.load_tasks

+task(:default).clear
+task(:spec).clear
+
 begin
   require "rspec/core/rake_task"
   RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new(:spec)
 rescue LoadError
 end

-task(:default).clear
 task default: [
   "factory_bot:lint",
   :spec,
 ]
```